# istio doesnt serve static files for prom helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

My team is using istio  (version 1.2.8) on our k8s (v 1.15.6)  landscape,
and we want to provide Prometheus with **external IP**, when applying the `vs` 
We were able to access Prometheus in the browser but without and `css/js` files. we got **404** error for the `.js` (see logs below) files (see envoy logs below) as the `/static` files are not served.

**This is the UI we got** (no css and js files are served)

[image]

instead of the following Prometheus default UI (when using loadbalancer or port forwarding...)

[image]

This is the minimal steps to see the issue:

Install [Prometheus](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus) via helm **as-is**(latest- **we didn't change any default** config of Prometheus from the chart  )

Take the name of the `service` (with `kubectl get svc` on the `ns` which the service deployed)   put it on the `destination->host` section in the VS (update the `gw` host etc) and apply the `VS` file

**vs.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prom-virtualservice
  namespace: mon
spec:
  gateways:
    - de-system-gateway.ws-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
    - lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
      rewrite:
        uri: /graph
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

BTW,

If I just change the type of Prometheus to use [`LoadBalancer`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L851) it work, I was able to get `external-ip` and see istio UI as expected.

another info, if I remove the following

```
      rewrite:
        uri: /graph
```

I got `404 error` in the browser without any data from prom

in the browser without js/css files , the network in the browser is like following:

[image]

I even try the following which doesn't work either

```
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
      rewrite:
        uri: /static
```

or

```
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus/static
```

our `gateway` spec looks like following

```
...
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
    port:
      name: https-manager
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/de-tls/tls.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/de-tls/tls.crt
```

using port forwarding (local) or `loadbalancer` for Prometheus it works. 
How can we make it work with istio ?

**update**

I've tried also to add the static and got the same results:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prom-virtualservice
  namespace: mon
spec:
  gateways:
    - de-system-gateway.ws-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
    - lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
        - uri:
            prefix: /static
        - uri:
            regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
      rewrite:
        uri: /graph
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

**update 2**

after using the yaml which provided as answer, now I see the ui with the css etc however it's not functional , I got error: `Error loading available metrics!` 
in the browser debug mode network tab I can see that the following is not working

This is the logs for envoy for the error

```
[2019-12-17T09:04:18.670Z] "GET /api/v1/query?query=time()&_=1576573457737 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "100.96.0.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "57592874-27f5-4b57-9dea-1bcf13365f60" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.13:443 100.96.0.1:24664 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
[2019-12-17T09:04:18.670Z] "GET /api/v1/label/__name__/values?_=1576573457738 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "100.96.0.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "edad441d-58fe-4214-aae0-a0aec9012030" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.13:443 100.96.0.1:24664 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
```

[image]

(we are not talking about Prometheus which comes with istio, we need to install diff Prometheus on diff namespace...)

**This is the logs from envoy**

2019-12-15T13:57:16.977357Z info    Envoy proxy is ready

[2019-12-15 14:29:51.226][14][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 13, 
[2019-12-15 15:00:50.980][14][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 13, 
**[2019-12-15T15:11:02.572Z] "GET /prometheus HTTP/2" 200 - "-" "-" 0 5785 2 1 "100.96.3.1"** "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "531e2f39-0c9f-44d3-b11b-e336126ea836" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "100.96.0.16:9090" outbound|80||prom-prometheus-server.mon.svc.cluster.local - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
**[2019-12-15T15:11:02.705Z] "GET /static/vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 -** "100.96.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "40119d8d-2103-4453-b589-e1561d44d363" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
**[2019-12-15T15:11:02.705Z] "GET /static/vendor/js/popper.min.js?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 -** "100.96.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "dbdf2a2a-cfd3-422a-82f4-e6e466407671" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
[2019-12-15T15:11:02.706Z] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap-4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "100.96.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "efd95571-03e9-492d-98ff-b4910d1646d6" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
[2019-12-15T15:11:02.706Z] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "100.96.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "8ae04546-06cb-4ba0-8430-f04388811460" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
[2019-12-15T15:11:02.706Z] "GET /static/css/prometheus.css?v=6f92ce56053866194ae5937012c1bec40f1dd1d9 HTTP/2" 404 NR "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "100.96.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0" "70c88f5f-b582-4dd9-a2e2-47605c812344" "lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn" "-" - - 100.96.2.10:443 100.96.3.1:32972 lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For start I found some information about [istio 1.2](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/) that tells

> Istio 1.2 has been tested with these Kubernetes releases: 1.12, 1.13, 1.14.

So if You use kubernetes 1.15 I would recommend to upgrade your istio to latest version.

---

About prometheus, I see You want to use prometheus helm chart, why won't You use built-in prometheus? As provided in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) prometheus is enabled in versions default,demo and sds.

---

Based on istio [remotely accessign telemetry addons](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/) You can use either secure([https](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#option-1-secure-access-https)) or insecure([http](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#option-2-insecure-access-http)) option to expose prometheus.

---

Personally i did an insecure reproduction by following above tutorial and everything is working.

**Kubernetes Version**: 1.13.11-gke.14

**Istio Version**: 1.4.2

Steps to follow

1.Install

- [Istioctl](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download)
- [Istio default](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#install-istio-using-the-default-profile)

2.Expose prometheus

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: prometheus-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 15030
      name: http-prom
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prometheus-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - prometheus-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 15030
    route:
    - destination:
        host: prometheus
        port:
          number: 9090
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: prometheus
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
---
EOF
```

3.Result

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Could You try use this yaml?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prom-virtualservice
  namespace: mon
spec:
  gateways:
    - de-system-gateway.ws-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
    - lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
  http:
  - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
      rewrite:
        uri: /graph
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
  - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /static
        - uri:
            regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

**EDIT2** Please add /api prefix to your second match like below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prom-virtualservice
  namespace: mon
spec:
  gateways:
    - de-system-gateway.ws-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
    - lzs.dev10.int.str.cloud.rpn
  http:
  - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
      rewrite:
        uri: /graph
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
  - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /static
        - uri:
            regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
        - uri:
            prefix: /api
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prom-prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

**EDIT3**

> In your answer you separate it to two matches , why?

This [link](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) is the answer here I think, You rewrite /prometheus to /graph since it's main Prometheus url, and that's okay. But you can't rewrite /static, /api to /graph because you need those paths to grab files and metrics, if it won't match then error 404 appears.

Comment: thanks, we are not talking about the Prometheus which comes with istio, we need to install fresh one and this doesnt works for us...

Comment: We need to install Prometheus (other than istio built in promethues)  in another `different namespace` with the default helm chart and provide external IP, did you try this ? does it works for you ?

Comment: btw, thanks for mentiones the version I've try it  also with k8s `v1.14.10` , which provide the same results :(

Comment: I will try to make it as soon as possible and let You know if it works. I think the answer here would be to add another matches here since prometheus is trying to request on /static and there is only /prometheus in your virtual service. Something like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rinormaloku/580a872b330e14111958aaac20f65aa6/raw/77c686b34c98a2261ea8b3066fca1a04d96b7af5/sa-virtualservice-external.yaml), You can read more about it on [medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/back-to-microservices-with-istio-p1-827c872daa53).

Comment: I've tried also to add static as new `uri` without any success (see my update in the post), it will be great if you can check it either as Im on dead end... :(

Comment: @NinaS i have edited my answer with yaml, could You try use it? Your won't work since everything is rewrited to /graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot expert! 1+ Now I see the UI which works however it not functional , you get an error `Error loading available metrics!` , does it works for you?

Comment: @NinaS Sure, envoy logs shows something new about those errors or no?

Comment: Done, Ive update the logs for envoy under update 2 in the question, does it helps to understand the issue?

Comment: @NinaS Updated the answer, check EDIT2.

Comment: I've closed the question. one last question/hint as I want to do it myself :) to learn better..., inside the ui there is tabs with buttons that not working now( not a problem for now) and I want to add also support for it, can you provide some hint for example how can I support the navigation to target ? or other button ? just need to add the prefix of the request from envoy as new uri ? thank you !

Comment: Actually it's what You said, another prefixes.

Comment: thanks, did it and it works :) , in your answer you separate it to two matches , why ?  I just want to understand it better...

Comment: @NinaS Updated the answer, check EDIT3 :)

Comment: Hi, I've new question on istio, maybe you can have a look :) , thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734184/istio-side-car-is-not-created