# istio side car is not created

Tags: kubernetes, istio

we have istio installed without the side car enabled gloablly , and I want to enable it to specific service in a new namespace

I’ve added to my  deployment the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gow
  labels:
    app: gowspec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gow
        tier: service
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
```

while running

`get namespace -L istio-injection` I don’t see anything enabled , everything is empty…

How can I verify that the side car is created ? I dont see anything new ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [istioctl](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) [kube-inject](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#manual-sidecar-injection) to make that

```
kubectl create namespace asdd
istioctl kube-inject -f nginx.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

---

nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: asdd
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "True"
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Result:

```
nginx-deployment-55b6fb474b-77788   2/2     Running   0          5m36s
nginx-deployment-55b6fb474b-jrkqk   2/2     Running   0          5m36s
```

Let me know if You have any more questions.

Comment: thanks for this command `istioctl kube-inject -f nginx.yaml | kubectl apply -f -` Im getting error : `Error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 3: could not find expected ':'
`  when I just apply the file and describe it I dont see the side car , any idea ?

Comment: I use the file as-is ... create ns and use istioctl

Comment: Im trying now to upgrade istioctl version

Answer (score 2):

You can describe your pod to see list of containers and one of those should be sidecar container. Look for something called istio-proxy.

```
kubectl describe pod pod name
```

It should look something like below

```
$ kubectl describe pod demo-red-pod-8b5df99cc-pgnl7
SNIPPET from the output:

Name:               demo-red-pod-8b5df99cc-pgnl7
Namespace:          default
.....
Labels:             app=demo-red
                    pod-template-hash=8b5df99cc
                    version=version-red
Annotations:        sidecar.istio.io/status={"version":"3c0b8d11844e85232bc77ad85365487638ee3134c91edda28def191c086dc23e","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"],"volumes":["istio-envoy","istio-certs...
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.32.0.6
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/demo-red-pod-8b5df99cc
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://bef731eae1eb3b6c9d926cacb497bb39a7d9796db49cd14a63014fc1a177d95b
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.0.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:e16a0746f46cd45a9f63c27b9e09daff5432e33a2d80c8cc0956d7d63e2f9185
    .....
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
    .....
    Ready:          True
Containers:
  demo-red:
    Container ID:   docker://8cd9957955ff7e534376eb6f28b56462099af6dfb8b9bc37aaf06e516175495e
    Image:          chugtum/blue-green-image:v3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker.io/chugtum/blue-green-image@sha256:274756dbc215a6b2bd089c10de24fcece296f4c940067ac1a9b4aea67cf815db
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 09 Dec 2018 18:12:31 -0800
    Ready:          True
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://ca5d690be8cd6557419cc19ec4e76163c14aed2336eaad7ebf17dd46ca188b4a
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.0.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/proxyv2@sha256:54e206530ba6ca9b3820254454e01b7592e9f986d27a5640b6c03704b3b68332
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      .....
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 09 Dec 2018 18:12:31 -0800
    Ready:          True
    .....
```

You need to have the admission webhook for automatic sidecar injection.

```
kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfiguration istio-sidecar-injector -o yaml | grep "namespaceSelector:" -A5
```

There may be many reasons for sidecar injection failures as described [here](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/#the-result-of-sidecar-injection-was-not-what-i-expected)

Here is a [table](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/injection-concepts/) which shows final injection status based on different scenarios.

Based on above table its mandatory to label the namespace with a label `istio-injection=enabled`

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled --overwrite
```

Comment: what should I search for in this output ?

Comment: and I see that the annotation is there (inside the output ) however I dont see any new container, how should I verfiy that it created ...?

Comment: I dont see in my side the init container , we didint enable the sidecar globally , we want for specific namespace and specific service to enable it ...

Comment: apart from the init container there should be istio-proxy

Comment: I am assuming you have the admission Webhook installed because that is what will inject the sidecar automatically.Do you see any error in Kube Api Server logs?

Comment: How could I verify it ?

Comment: Can you label your namespace kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled --overwrite

Comment: run this to check if web hook is configured - kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfiguration istio-sidecar-injector -o yaml | grep "namespaceSelector:" -A5